# Java 1.8 URLDecoder alternatives

Tags: java

I have the following code which make URL/post body decode:

```java
String getUrl = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(getUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String postData = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(postData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

When I'm trying to run it (I must use Java 1.8) I got the following:

```
>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -jar myjar.jar GET https://my.url/path
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.net.URLDecoder.decode(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

What is my alternative to decode URL (with same charsets - UTF8) using Jdk 1.8 (Unable to upgrade)?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to pass the charset as a String, i.e. as an argument you could pass to Charset.forName()

Comment: @tgdavies meaning```java.net.URLDecoder.decode(getUrl, "UTF-8")``` do the same like ```java.net.URLDecoder.decode(getUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)``` ?

Comment: The fact that you can compile this without errors but get an error at runtime means you're compiling it with a different version of Java than what you're running it with. To catch mistakes at compile time, it's better to use the same version of Java for compiling and running your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [UrlDecoder#decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) indicates that the signature of the method is `(String, String) -> String` (both arguments are Strings), while you're passing `String` and `Charset`. You can change the second parameter to `String` for instance by calling `Charset#name`:

```
String getUrl = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(getUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```